# Using matplotlib GTK3Agg Backend in jupyterhub notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, gtk3, jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub

I just started a jupyterhub server so that I can save all my data on one machine and have collaborators connect to access the data. Part of the code uses a GTK window which I normally launch from an ipython notebook. The error I get is `TypeError: constructor returned NULL` ([full traceback](https://gist.github.com/m3wolf/2b3abf368f2fb6f7874c)). I can pretty easily reproduce this by making a new notebook and running `from matplotlib import pyplot` since by default it uses the GTK backend of my system.

So this works if I run it from the conventional jupyter-notebook and not through jupyterhub even if the notebook is accessed from the same computer that the server is running on. I recognize that many clients won't be able to load the GTK components if they don't have it installed themselves so I structured the software so that Gtk/Gdk only get imported when necessary. If I can't use it at all, though, then I will have to abandon the jupyterhub idea and think of something else.

Comment: You will need to switch to using the `%maplotlib nbagg` backend.

Comment: also keep an eye on the coming phosphor work.

Comment: nbagg looks interesting but I don't really need the gtk panning window. I have a FigureCanvasGTK3Agg as part of a gtk window with other controls that aren't in the regular matplotlib viewing window.

Comment: For anyone coming to this in the future, I am planning on re-writing the GUI using ipython widgets: https://github.com/ipython/ipywidgets

Comment: You should also keep an eye on https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/5754  which should make this sort of thing easier.